# VNC input extremely laggy on Linux Mint install

Tags: linux-mint, x11vnc

Running a headless Linux Mint (19.3) server for Plex and Homebridge.  I only mange it via SSH or VNC.  Currently running x11vnc (0.9.13) with the following config

```
-noxrecord -ncachecr -auth guess -forever -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc/vncpwd -rfbport -shared
```

Everything works fine except input lag on VNC is nearly unbearable. Typing is about a character every 2 seconds and mouse movement/clicks are also very slow.  When the screen changes eg showing some sort of animation, it seems to be at a near normal pace that I'd expect for VNC.  Also when I SSH to the machine, everything is perfectly speedy.

Not sure where to go or what to do from here

Comment: Local wired. Please provide a ``tracepath`` from the headless server to your client.